# I caught an Eevee, which of its evolutions will it evolve into?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I just caught an Eevee. Now, I need 25 candies to evolve it. The fact is that in the GameBoy color versions, that Pokémon needed a stone to evolve instead of experience. Depending of the stone he was fed with (thunder, water or fire), he was evolving in a different Pokémon.

Is the stone feature also in Pokémon Go? If not, what decide the evolution of this Pokémon?

Bonus point : If it's possible, how can I get a stone?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Evolution stones as you know them (water, fire, etc.) don't exist in the current version of *Pokémon GO*. By default, when you evolve an Eevee in *Pokémon GO*, the [evolution is chosen randomly](http://www.kotaku.com.au/2016/07/heres-some-tips-for-playing-pokemon-go/) from the first set of potential "eeveelutions" (Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon).

To get other Eeveelutions like Espeon/Umbreon, other requirements must be met. See [@MBorg's answer for more details](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351654/28182).

There is also a method for forcing a specific evolution by giving your Eevee a certain nickname before it evolves. See [@Brant's answer for more details](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275146/81131).

Comment: I heard some(?) of Gen II is here, any Espeon or Umbreon info?

Comment: @SeeOneRhino Feel free to update the answer if you have any information. I have not been keeping up.

Answer (score 105):

According to [this post on the /r/pokemongo subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4svayv/how_to_choose_your_eeveelution/), you can force your Eevee to evolve a certain way by changing its nickname before evolving it to:

- *Pyro* to evolve into **Flareon**.
- *Sparky* to evolve into **Jolteon**.
- *Rainer* to evolve into **Vaporeon**.

(These are the names of [Eevee Brothers](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_brothers) from the TV series/Manga)

You can also, as of the Generation II update, use nicknames to evolve into a certain Eeveelution, but like before, this works only once.

- *Tamao* to evolve into **Umbreon**.
- *Sakura* to evolve into **Espeon**.

This now works with the Generation IV evolutions Leafeon and Glaceon. When renaming Eevee the first time, the evolve button with display the evolution it will evolve into rather than a question mark.

- *Linnea* to evolve into **Leafeon**
- *Rea* to evolve into **Glaceon**

This technique will only work **once** per evolution. For example, if you have already evolved an Eevee named *Rainer* into a Vaporeon, evolving another Eevee named *Rainer* will result in a random evolution.

Evolving without the naming tricks will give you Flareon, Jolteon or Vaporeon by random chance.

Also, [according to another reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ukcyq/umbreon_evolution_method_confirmed_10km_walked/), by walking 10km with Eevee as a buddy you will get Espeon when evolving during the day and Umbreon when evolving during the night.

Answer (score 15):

### Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon

Evolving an Eevee without meeting any other requirements/prerequisites, will randomly result in either a **Vaporeon, Jolteon, or Flareon** with a 1/3 chance of either of them.

### Espeon, Umbreon

If you keep Eevee as your buddy for 10km, earn at least 2 candy with it whilst it's your buddy, and then evolve it whilst it's your buddy, [it will evolve into either](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/gen-2-evolutions-guide):

- **Espeon** if evolved during the day.
- **Umbreon** if evolved during the night.

The 10km and 2 candy requirement is counted across all buddy uses of Eevee. You can earn the kilometers and candy, either intermittently or all at once, whilst changing buddies or keeping it the same.

As long as a total of 10km and 2 candy has been earned whilst Eevee has been a buddy, **and** you evolve it whilst the Eevee is currently set to your buddy. It will override the ability to evolve into Vaporeon/Jolteon/Flareon whilst it's your buddy, but not Leafeon/Glaceon if near the relevant lure.

Day vs night is determined by the game screen in the overworld/map. [It's daytime when it is bright, and nighttime when it's dark:](https://www.imore.com/pokemon-go-eevee-evolutions)

[image: Day vs Night]

The times when the game screen changes over [varies depending on your GPS and time location.](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/98lw2n/time_to_evolve_eevee_for_espeonumbreon/)

### Leafeon, Glaceon

If a Moss or Icy Rock is placed on a Pokestop (can be purchased from the shop for 200 coins, or someone else can place the Rock) and then evolve Eevee whilst in the radius of the Rock, [it will evolve into **Leafeon** (Moss Rock) or **Glaceon** (Icy Rock).](https://www.gamepur.com/news/40594-how-catch-glaceon-and-leafeon-pokemon-go.html)

The silhouette of Leafeon/Glaceon will appear if these requirements are met prior to evolution - if it doesn't, the requirements are not met and it would evolve into Vaporeon/Jolteon/Flareon (or Espeon/Umbreon if their conditions are met).

### Syvleon

Earn at least 70 hearts with your Eevee so that it becomes a Great Buddy (also works with Ultra and Best buddy). Afterwards, whilst Eevee your buddy, you are given the option to evolve it into Sylveon. Unlike the other evolution methods, the option to evolve into Sylveon is available simultaneously alongisde Espeon/Umbreon and Leafeon/Glaceon if those conditions are met.

---

[You can also choose a nickname to force a specific evolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275146/219593), but this only works *once* per nickname/evolution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first three evolutions mentioned by @Brant, with the addition of the second generation there are two more Eevee names that will trigger a guaranteed evolution once:

- *Tamao* for an Umbreon.
- *Sakura* for an Espeon.

Comment: I've edited it into @Brant's original answer. This is a useless answer now.

Comment: This should also be added to answers of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275194/how-can-i-force-my-eevee-to-evolve-into-the-pokemon-i-want?).

Comment: @Jouramie that is not necessary. That was marked a dupe of this question so users will be redirected here anyways.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/gen-2-evolutions-guide), stones are available after the gen 2 update. Other than the naming tricks, there are other ways to control some evolution forms:

Walk with the Eevee for 10 kilometers and stay it as your buddy, then evolve it during: day – Espeon; night: Umbreon.

There may be other better ways to control evolutions, but haven't been found out by all trainers.

Answer (score -10):

It depends on what move your Eevee knows when you capture it. Here is the move to evolution chart
:

- Swift - Vaporeon
- Dig - Jolteon
- Body Slam - Flareon

Comment: Do you have any source?

Comment: I'm seeing people test this on [reddit right now](https://m.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s135q/lets_test_how_the_eeveelution_system_works/), and if you look at the people posting results, you'll see that there are people whose "Dig" Eevees evolved into Vaporeons and Jolteons.

Comment: I tried this last night. Myth busted. Could post video proof in the evening if really necessary

Answer (score -16):

Well I've evolved two Eevees so far and I've had my friend evolve one and this is the conclusion I came to:

It depends on your team. I am Team Mystic (blue) and both times i got Vaporeon, my friend is team Valor and he got Flareon.

Is there anyone who disagrees? ^_^

Comment: That is a possibility, but it's hard to believe without sources as it would mean that at all you can't capture every Pokémon.

Comment: I'm on Team Blue and got Jolteon, so I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Team Yellow and I got Vaporeon.

Comment: Furthermore, when they add Gen2 Pokemon (what I think will eventually be done) this theory breaks, too. Or they would add Team Black and Grey.

Comment: Mystic, and I got Jolteon.