# Is there any way to ensure that Eevee evolves into its other forms?

Tags: pokemon-go

Across the different versions of Pokémon, Eevee has many evolutions. Is it possible to choose what evolution we get when we evolve an Eevee?

From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_(Pok%C3%A9mon)):

> **Umbreon** when leveled up with high friendship during the nighttime
>   (Generation II onward, excludes areas with a Moss Rock or Ice Rock),
>   or when leveled up with a Moon Shard in the Bag (Pokémon XD).
>
> **Glaceon** when leveled up near an Ice Rock (Generation IV onward).

We don't have Moss or Ice rocks, just Eevee candies. Is the evolution in Pokémon GO random, or is there a way to control which evolution is chosen?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/i-caught-an-eevee-in-which-of-its-evolutions-will-it-evolve?rq=1 Although, to be fair, some of the info there conflicts with reports in small ways elsewhere. But the nicknames are the gist of what you want.

Comment: @Ellesedil Ah, didn't know about the subsequent edit to that answer that talked about the nicknaming method. This can probably be marked as a dupe to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, only the first generation of Pokémon (the first 151) are available in Pokémon GO. That means that Flareon, Jolteon, and Vaporeon are currently the only available Eevee evolutions.

That being said, you can still decide which evolution you get [by nicknaming your Eevee before evolving it](https://www.vg247.com/2016/07/27/pokemon-go-heres-how-to-choose-one-of-three-evolutions-for-eevee/):

- `Pyro` for Flareon
- `Sparky` for Jolteon
- `Rainer` for Vaporeon

This trick [has been reported](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t5fed/im_hearing_from_people_that_rainersparkypyro_now/) to now only work once per account, however, so if you've already used the name `Rainer` to get a Vaporeon then it won't guarantee a Vaporeon evolution for subsequent attempts.

Comment: Keep in mind that there seems to be a limit in place to only allow this to actually work once per account for each of the possibilities.  Many people, myself included, have used this method to get the full set only to try again and have it fail.

Comment: @Prof.Bear Yup, I saw that recently reported, and edited that in. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: @Prof.Bear: About 50% of my "Rainer" Eevees have evolved into Vaporeon. There's reports that you need to ensure that the Niantic servers are synced up with your nicknames for it to work more reliably. I'm trying to prove this out, since I have access to a lot of Eevees (I've caught over 100).

Comment: Finally was able to try this and successfully evolved Eevee into Jolteon and Vaporeon :D

Comment: @Ellesedil: did you ever come to a conclusion?

Comment: @hertitu: No, but I do currently have 21 Eevees (some with great stats) and 272 Eevee candy. At some point, I'll start seeing if I can dictate their evolutions.