# Why didn't the Eevee-evolution-name trick work?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know the trick that lets you force the eevolution by giving a nickname to the Eevee, but I named my eevee 'Rainer' and it was my first time ever doing so, yet it turned into a Jolteon.

I don't know why this happened, so can someone please tell me why?

Comment: I'm gonna bet you mistyped it.

Comment: I definitely named it Rainer because I checked the spelling twice before evolving it

Comment: (edit)... except the next answer covers me.  I was trying to create a second Vaporeon because my first is stuck in a remote gym that gets no traffic.  Free coins, but my primary attacker is tied up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should restart Pokemon Go after naming it *Rainer* to make sure the game actually changes the name and registers it, and if so, **then** evolve your Eevee. If the name change didn't stick, change it again and restart again.

Further to this, if you already evolved a Eevee into a Vaporeon by using the *Rainer* name, **it will not work again**, and the Eevee will just change into a random evolution, like Jolteon or Flareon. This goes for all the Eeveelutions as well.

Also check out this link for even more information about the evolutions:  [I caught an Eevee, which of its evolutions will it evolve into?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/i-caught-an-eevee-in-which-of-its-evolutions-will-it-evolve?rq=1)

Comment: This is an important check to make, if you don't fully close out the app and restart it there's always a chance the server didn't register your change since they're still iffy at the best of times.

Comment: I sadly have made this exact mistake before. Super annoying with the random server issues!

Comment: So before doing it again I need to restart Pokemon go?

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily true that you *need* to, it may be a failsafe or help ensure that it works, but I evolved all three of mine successfully after renaming without restarting.

Comment: I've read that it only works, if you haven't discovered the Eevee evolution before. So not just, if you do it for the first time. It's a small but important different.

Comment: Some phones may automatically add a whitespace at the end of the Pokémon's name, which if present will stop the name trick from working. If you're sure nothing else here applies, check to see if you've had an automatic whitespace added to the name.

Answer (score 5):

I'm close to hitting lvl 31 so I've had some experience with this issue.

Restarting Pokemon Go has been a huge success for most but I've seen cases myself where it did not work even then.

Ever since I've always given the servers some time after the restart, e.g. just a few minutes, to let the name sink in. Every evolution has worked since then. I've evolved a few and so have my friends.

It's possible that the game is picking up the new name from the phone's cache (which I happen to clear out just in case before evolving) instead of picking it right up from the server. Clearing the cache for this specific app should enforce the game to load the name from the server if it used to pick it up from cache.

The time that occurs during the restart might be enough but like I said: I've seen cases where it was simply not enough. It's very possible that restarting is not required at all, simply waiting might be enough. Better safe than sorry though!

Conclusion: Restart and give it some time. Consider clearing the game's cache if you want to be extra safe and make sure the game can't load the name from your phone and force it to load it from the server.

I understand that this is a little messy and it's hard to give a 100% working one way answer but without spoofing and experimenting a lot with different ways it's safer to do all the things that make it likely to work.

Good luck!

EDIT: A few updates after I posted this it no longer seems to work. I'm not sure whether it was luck all along or whether it was a bug that allowed us to do this multiple times, if so it seems to have been fixed. It seems to be pretty much random now but if anything changes I'll update.

Comment: Im pretty new to this so what do you mean by restarting Pokemon go? Do you mean close the app and open it up again?

Comment: Yeah just that. I even use the Force Stop feature in Android on the app before evolving. Probably not necessary but I'm playing it safe and so far it has worked. I'll make sure to make edits if something goes wrong one day.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me the first four times I did it. Then I got a Flareon instead of Vape. Someone mentioned cycling through all the names might help so I evolved Sparky, got a Jolteon. Evolved Pyro... Got a Vaporeon. So, perhaps there is a limit as speculated, having nothing to do with cycling and naming after the first few.

Answer (score -1):

I Have used this trick 5 times and each time it worked until the last 2 times. I used the Rainer and instead of a Vape I got 1 flareon and 1 Jolt. well I named the Evee used the last a week before its evolving this time and it still turned into a jolt. I will try clearing out my phones cache if I can but I think that the trick is over

Comment: It only works once. Trying it again has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score -4):

After many unwanted Flareons I found a pattern. I did everything suggested here and other forums however, I always named it Rainer but always got a Flareon. So I learned that if you want Vaporeon, name it Sparky, and if your want Flareon name it Rainer. I mean, its like using the name of the type thats "contrary" to the the one you want. For me it has worked flawlessly up to now.