# Is there a way to control or predict Tyrogue's evolution?

Tags: pokemon-go

Tyrogue, like Eevee, can evolve into different Pokémon. It's possible to [control which evolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272930/32055) Eevee turns into. Is there a similar method for Tyrogue?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**TL;DR** - This is determined by the Pokemon's highest [IV](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/276692):

- Attack ⇒ Hitmonlee
- Defense ⇒ Hitmonchan
- Health ⇒ Hitmontop
- Equal Stats ⇒ Random of the evened values

---

You cannot force Tyrogue to evolve into one of the three evolution's like Eevee, but in recent updates, you can see which evolution it will evolve into

**Defense is highest IV**

[image: Tyrogue -> Hitmonchan]

**Attack is highest IV**

[image: Tyrogue -> Hitmonchan]

**IVs that are equal**

[image: Tyrogue -> Random]

Comment: What about if something else, such as speed, is the highest IV? Is this even possible? (I'm new to pokemon go)

Comment: @hammythepig There's no speed IV. Speed doesn't vary by individual, only type.