# Can an Eevee evolve into Umbreon/Espeon "randomly"?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am aware that there is a
["naming trick"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275146/75983)
which you can use to evolve an Eevee into an Umbreon or Espeon.

I am also aware that [you can walk with an Eevee for 10 km as your buddy,
then if you evolve that Eevee at night/day,
you will get an Umbreon/Espeon](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ukcyq/umbreon_evolution_method_confirmed_10km_walked/).

My question is: Is it possible for Eevee
to randomly evolve into Umbreon or Espeon?
So far, my random evolutions of Eevee
have resulted in only Vaporeon, Flareon and Jolteon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, an Eevee will only evolve into an Umbreon or Espeon if it has been walked as a buddy for at least 10km and is your buddy at the time you evolve it.

If this criteria has been met, Espeon/Umbreon *will* be the Pokémon your Eevee evolves into. The determining factor for which of the two you will receive is time of day— a daytime evolution will net you an Espeon, while a nighttime evolution will result in an Umbreon.

Comment: For additional information: I believe daytime is considered 6am-6pm, while nighttime is considered 6pm-6am local time.

Comment: @Kadima, Silph Road researchers actually [determined a formula](https://thesilphroad.com/science/quick-discovery/sunrise-sunset-times-determined/) to indicate sunrise/sunset.